# Install every version or latest version is enough for android?

Tags: android, sdk, installation

I am very new to the android development. I currently installed Android 4.0.3(API 15) via android sdk manager. I am in great confusion if this version is enough to develop the android apps or we should install from Android 1.5 (API 3) to the latest. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends which versions you want to support.

This depends on your users and features you use.

(Also, I hate the emulator, so depends on what device you actually have access to!)

If you're only playing around and figuring things out don't worry about it and just use the most recent.

To get a sense of what each version has changed, take a look at the platform highlights:

- [4.0](http://developer.android.com/sdk/android-4.0-highlights.html)
- [3.2](http://developer.android.com/sdk/android-3.2.html)
- [3.1](http://developer.android.com/sdk/android-3.1.html)
- [3.0](http://developer.android.com/sdk/android-3.0.html)
- [2.3.4](http://developer.android.com/sdk/android-2.3.4.html)
- [2.3.3](http://developer.android.com/sdk/android-2.3.3.html)
- [2.2](http://developer.android.com/sdk/android-2.2.html)
- [2.1](http://developer.android.com/sdk/android-2.1.html)

With regards to learning, 4 is much better than 3, since 4 is open source, so you can look at the source. In fact if you're using Eclipse, you can [browse the source within your project](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9417828/186636)!

Comment: Dear sir, thanks for quick response. I want my apps support all versions of androids. So with the latest version only is not it possible to test for the old one?

Comment: @user1090751 -  
If you want to support all versions you have to install and test all versions. Things are not completely forward or backwards compatible. New features are added w each release, and - for example - I've noticed that DialogFragment layout has changed from 3.2 to 4.0, so some DialogFragments that look good in 3.2 do not in 4.0.